# How do I form a linked list while iterating over the digits of a number?

Tags: python, linked-list

I want to form a linked list which is reversed in order of the digits of the number. For eg, if the number is 523, the linked list would be 3->2->5.

I tried iterating over the number and forming a list but I am unable to deduce how do I form a linked list in O(n)?!
My current codebase is stuck here:

```
def form_linked_list(self, number):
    final_list = ListNode(number%10)
    number = int(number/10)
    while(number):
        final_list.next = ListNode(number%10)
        number = int(number/10)
    return final_list
```

I expect to form a linked list from the given number in reverse order. I am unable to deduce the logic to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I work on digit problems I like to decouple the digit extraction from anything I wind up doing with the digits.

```
def digits(n):
  # requires n >= 0, counts 0 as having no digits
  while n:
    yield n%10
    n //= 10

head = cur = ListNode(0)  # not part of the final list
for x in digits(number):
  cur.next = ListNode(x)
  cur = cur.next
head = head.next
```

When you iterate over the digits you need to deal with the creation of the first ListNode (if it exists) being slightly different from the rest of the ListNodes since it doesn't have a parent. I side-stepped this by creating a fake starting point so that all the digits could be treated uniformly and then ignoring the extra object. You're doing all this in a function anyway, so the garbage collector can take care of it.

Comment: Thanks Hans!
Could you also tell me how come changes in `curr` made changes in `head` as well?

Comment: Sure. The key concepts here are **variables** and **objects**. When you start out, `head` and `cur` are *different* variables that point to the *same* object. When you assign `cur.next = ListNode(x)` this is exactly the same as saying `head.next = ListNode(x)` -- at least the first time. The next thing we do is reassign the variable `cur` to point to the object `cur.next`, so the next assignment that happens when we write `cur.next = ListNode(x)` is basically the same thing as `head.next.next = ListNode(x)`. And so on with `head.next.next.next` and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on string reversing:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

def form_linked_list(number):
    number_str = str(number)[::-1]

    if number_str:
        head = ListNode(number_str[0])
    for idx in range(1,len(number_str)):
        if idx == 1:
            head.next = ListNode(int(number_str[idx]))
            temp = head.next
        else:
            temp.next = ListNode(int(number_str[idx]))
            temp = temp.next

    return head

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result =form_linked_list(523)
    while(result):
        print(result.val)
        result = result.next
```

and the output is:

```
1
3
2
```